# Relative positioning of shapes VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that creates shapes on top of shapes, I would like it to create shapes next to each other and not on top. How can I do that?

```
  Sub removercaixas(strName As String)

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In Worksheets(2).Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox And shp.Name = strName Then shp.Delete
    Next shp

End Sub
Sub criarcaixastexto(strName As String)

    Dim wsActive As Worksheet
    Dim box As Shape

    Set wsActive = Worksheets(2)
    Set box = wsActive.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 20, 20, 100, 50)

    box.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Worksheets(1).Range(strName).Value
    box.Name = strName

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$A$1", "$A$2", "$A$3"
            removercaixas (Target.Address)
            If Len(Target) > 0 Then criarcaixastexto (Target.Address)
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: the arguments in the AddTextbox method are the location and size of the textbox

Comment: I know, I just don't know how to make them relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying `criarcaixastexto` to the below will set each text box relatively to which cell you are changing:

```
Sub criarcaixastexto(strName As String)

    Dim wsActive As Worksheet
    Dim box As Shape

    Set wsActive = Worksheets(2)

    Dim leftpos as Long

    'this can be tidied up, i just left math so you can see logic
    Select Case strName
        Case is = "$A$1": leftpos = 20 'first one
        Case is = "$A$2": leftpos = 20 + 100 + 20 'first one plus width + padding
        Case is = "$A$3": leftpos = 20 + 100 + 20 + 100 + 20 'second one plus width plus padding 
    End Select

    Set box = wsActive.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, leftpos, 20, 100, 50)

    box.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Worksheets(1).Range(strName).Value
    box.Name = strName

End Sub
```

Comment: if you want the text boxes placed relative to left side of cells then remove the case statement altogether and use `leftpos = Worksheets(1).Range(strName).Left`

Comment: The problem is that my code is just an example that I will then replicate to a more complex worksheet, were I have dozens of cells not just three

Comment: @user7409049 - Then you should write your question accordingly. This code addresses the question **as written**. If your problem is different than what you state, then delete this question and ask a new one. Lastly, this answer was meant more to provide concept of execution. You can modify as needed.